# directive change ngmodel input value from contexmenu

Tags: angular, contextmenu, ngmodel

i create a directive that display a custom context menu and when i select an item ,
the value binds to the input,
the problem is that value is displayed but the ([ngModel]) not changed and after save nothing is updated.
so how can i change the ngModel? thank you

Answer (score 0):

the one way that worked for me is :

```
const ctrl = this.ngControl.control;
ctrl.setValue(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
```